# are there any pitfalls to using lockfile over sshfs?

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, locking, sshfs

I have inherited a project that involves setting up a test environment (based on amazon ec2 instances).

Here's the architecture:

- A single always-on instance contains a folder foo that contains various setup scripts;
- N other instances are booted on demand. N can be anything from 10 to 1000;
- These N instances, at boot time, mount "foo" over sshfs;
- They then run various setup (bash) scripts - one of which writes to a common {{/etc/hosts}} file.

One logical concern is that the N instances could hit some kind of race condition while writing to the same file concurrently. So I want to do some kind of file-locking. I found out about [`lockfile`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lockfile) but I do not know enough about sshfs or file-locking.

So:

- Are there any possible pitfalls to using `lockfile` on a file mounted over sshfs? I have not found any literature online for/against this.
- Any suggestions to completely avoid this situation altogether?

Comment: There are always pitfalls using network file locking. My advice is don't. In fact my advice is don't use network files in applications at all.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, though, the SSHFS mount is pretty-much non-negotiable for various reasons - I am not administrating the project, etc etc. Have to work with it for now at least.

Comment: Instead of `lockfile /mnt/some-sshfs/something.lock`, can you try `ssh someone@always-on-instance lockfile /tmp/something.lock` ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple test with mounting a directory over sshfs and locking a file therein and then locking the same file on the host server showed me that the LOCK IS NOT RECOGNIZED.  Now the disclaimer is that I am using perl on both machines, and I am not 100% certain what it is using as flock() since the documentation says that it uses a variety of OS calls.  I am however using the same OS, ubuntu 20.04 and the same perl, 5.30.